# Wordpress unnecessary redirections. How to fix the issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, seo

Hello community i came up with a strange problem and i think it's the .htacces causing the problem. I run a WORDPRESS site and i check it with a SEO toolkit (Microsoft). 
When the report finishes it come up with some violations:
"The link to "http://www.example.com/?p=11" has resulted in HTTP redirection to "http://www.example.com/example/".
-I activated permalinks inside wordpress.
-I using SEO by yoast plugin.
-My .htaccess file is:

```
`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress`
```

Any idea how can i remove invalid redirections ?
Thanks all !

Comment: What exactly is your problem? A bad redirect (bad for SEO according to this tool) or a invalid redirects (which would not work at all)?

Comment: Yeah, isn't this the desired behaviour? Wordpress puts these redirects in place when you change to pretty permalinks so that any old links to the /?p=postid will still work, but from now on all WP created links will go to the pretty url ie /postname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the official url of your web page is www.example.com/example/, than ideally the user will never see a page  "www.example.com/?p=11" . So the redirect is not bad in this case. It may even be good, so that google knows which of theses urls should be the one it should index.
It is only bad if you still have links somewhere that still have the form "www.example.com?p=11". But than these links are the problem, not the redirect.

Comment: Yep it is the official page. Made through wordpress permalinks automatic. But my problem is why seo toolkit warn me and how i clean up these links ? Thanks :)

Comment: @JohnGeorgoudakis, if you are concern of an SEO thing and you have no idea to hardcode or tweak on htaccess use this instead http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/